# Why pm2 NodeJS app starts but not accessible on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, pm2

I have a Nodejs app running on AWS EC2. My `package.json` has the following instructions:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -s -D -d dist --presets es2015,stage-0",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
..
```

So when connected to EC2 I (after install and cd to proj folder) I do `PORT=8080 npm start` The app starts fine - but messages in the console and is acessinble via my EC2 addres :8080. Also if I run PORT=8080 node dist/index.js
 - also good.

But since I would like to use monitoring, restarting of the script by **pm2** I try do following:

```
 pm2 start dist/index.js -- PORT=8080
```

or

```
 PORT=8080 pm2 start dist/index.js
```

I see that pm2 has the app started, 
[image]

but it's not acessible on AWS address :8080

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried restarting pm2?
 This line ` PORT=8080 pm2 start dist/index.js` is the correct format. https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/83#issuecomment-29837221

Comment: Thanks! doing `pm2 kill` before starting helped!